# How to prevent files with "console.log" to be committed?

Tags: git, eslint, pre-commit-hook, husky

I'm currently trying to enforce that me or my colleague cannot commit files that contains console.log in my angular application.

I currently already have `husky` on pre-commit, that execute a `ng lint --fix`.

Is there a way to either add something to my linting to prevent console log, or to add something in the husky script?

People should still be able to use console.log, just not commit it.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can go to your project's `tslint.json` file and make sure this option is present in your file:

```json
{
    "rules": {
        "no-console": true
    }
}
```

If you prefer something that won't "block" you but just warn you, you also can set this option as follows:

```json
{
   "rules": {
      "no-console": {
         "severity": "warning",
      } 
   }
}
```

And finally, if you want to target some `console` functions more precisely, you can specify them like this:

```json
{
    "rules": {
        "no-console": {
            "severity": "warning",
            "options": [
                "log",
                "error",
                "debug",
                "info",
                "time",
                "timeEnd",
                "trace"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this the same with eslint? Seems that now it's what is used by default on angular project. Also, the rules doesn't seems to have the same format?

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a `.gitignore`file contaninig this:

```
console.log
```

With this your log file will be generated, but not commited.

EDIT

You can't ignore file by content with gitignore.

Instead, you can exlude files with shell script, like this:

```
for file in $(git grep -l --cached 'console.log') ; do
    git rm --cached $file
done
```

Comment: It's not a file named console.log but a file containing console.log that I don't want

Comment: I update my response

Comment: I don't want to ignore them, I want to prevent my user to commit if one of its file to commit contains it

Comment: That's it! The script remove from local git repository all files that contain ``console.log``, thus, if removed from local repository the files won't be commited. But the local files is not deleted. 
If this is not what yout want, can you explicitely tell me what you want.

Comment: The whole commit should be prevented. There has be changes in this file, probably not only this console.log. It's not coherent to allow to commit for a feature with only part of the files. It should be like our linting, that prevent the user to commit if it doesn't respect the guidelines